# IabResult: Billing service unavailable on device. (response: 3:Billing Unavailable)

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I'm trying to use In-App billing:

```
mIabHelper = new IabHelper(this, BILLING_KEY);
        mIabHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);
                }
            }
        });
```

And getting the error:

```
Problem setting up In-app Billing: IabResult: Billing service unavailable on device. (response: 3:Billing Unavailable)
```

Why? Tried to clear cache of the Play Store, didn't work for me.

Comment: question: where do You init all stuff about IAB - in activity or in Application? IAB 3.0 gives code example with that car, whole code is in Activity however they also say no to do in .. Activity. Where do You do things with getting purche list and etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wipe helped me. Strange error.

Comment: Wipe what? and How?

Comment: @ArsalanShah Device wipe — reset settings

Comment: Please explain more about this..

Comment: On a physical device try Settings - Apps- select your app - clear data. On emulator: close it and in Android studio Device manager find your emulator - three dots - Wipe data. On emulator you will need to run Play store app to sign in in your Google account.

Answer (score 49):

Well we can't help you without having much information.So instead I'll try to do a checklist for you in case you missed something:

1. Are you testing on an emulator?Billing services should be tested on devices,BUT if you 
   really have to test on the emulator,make sure the emulator has google play installed and set up.This is very important!
2. Did you set the correct permission in the manifest? (com.android.vending.BILLING)
3. If you are still testing the app,did you get a test app licence from the playstore, imported the level in your SDK ,set up your licence verification library? (you can follow along here: [setting up](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html)
4. On your activity onActivityResult did you correctly handle the activity result?As seen on the example from google you should do it this way:

---

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
  Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult(" + requestCode + "," + resultCode + "," + data);

  // Pass on the activity result to the helper for handling
  if (!inappBillingHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }
  else {
    Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");
  }
}
```

Also having more information could be useful, like if you are testing on the emulator or device, the device name, the android version etc...

Comment: 1. No, it's real device with G. Play installed
2. Yes
3. Yes, I followed all the instructions
4. The library is failed to initialize, I didn't tried to go further

Answer (score 6):

This error indicates that you're connecting to the in-app billing service on your device, but that the service doesn't support IAB version 3.  It may be that your device's version of Google Play only supports version 2 of IAB.  What version of Google Play is running on your device?

Is your version of Google Play otherwise functional (e.g., can you open the Google Play store)?  Sometimes, if the date on your device is off, or there is some other problem, Google Play itself can go South.

Finally, what's in your logcat output?  It would be easier to provide assistance if you provided more detail.

Comment: I've wiped the device and it works fine now. That's very strange.

Comment: If Google Play was in fact corrupted, then that may have fixed it.  A less extreme action would have been to uninstall all updates for the Google Play application, and then allow them to re-install, although that may or may not have worked.

Answer (score 6):

I got that error when I installed the App BEFORE I registered everything and set Google Play store up. Once I set the Google Play Store account up, the error went away.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for version 2.0 of the billing was actually more helpful than 3.0 for this one even though I'm using version 3.0 of the billing.

**Here's how 2.0 describes it Response Code 3:**

> Indicates that In-app Billing is not available because the API_VERSION
>   that you specified is not recognized by the Google Play application ***or
>   the user is ineligible for in-app billing*** (for example, the user
>   resides in a country that prohibits in-app purchases).

For me I had to setup a test Google account on my phone first before testing.  I forgot that step.  Once I did that fixed it for me...

**Look for Server Response Codes here:**

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/v2/billing_reference.html

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html

Comment: Is there anyway you can put a check around the calls that will display to the user to make sure an account is registered with Google Play? I know this is probably overkill as the device must have an account in order to download the app, but would be good to have a proper check to take care of the error and display to the user rather than just crashing?

Comment: I am receiving "Init failed - Setup failed. BILLING_UNAVAILABLE: Billing service unavailable on device." in a Cordova app on Huawei AGS3-L09 (i.e. Huawei MatePad T 10s). I believe this also happens if the device doesn't have GMS (new Huawei devices instead have HMS).

Answer (score 3):

I found a problem to fix, try root with ur LuckyPatcher, open config Toggles -> Disable billing.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly this error when I removed all Google accounts from phone (thus wipe fixes because after wipe you probably set up an account after phone rebooted).

After I added an account I did not see this error.

Related issue [What are the possibilities to get this error code 3 in InApp purchase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091353/what-are-the-possibilities-to-get-this-error-code-3-in-inapp-purchase).

Comment: Same here. I had this problem on an emulator. The problem went away once I opened the Google Play app and signed in.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem.

My device was rooted and ROM'ed with an older version of Google Market which did not self-update.
You can verify your the Market/Play version by looking at it in the AppManager.

I actually decided to use another device, but I guess otherwise I would have to find a way to upgrade the Market/Play version.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error from wiping the Google Play cache.  You have to reopen the Google Play app and accept the terms before it is functional for IAB again.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the account which is currently logged in the device is not registered in Google Developer Console.
TO resolve this problem,
1. Go to your Google Developer Consol
2. In Account Detail Tab, enter the email address(which is in device) in "Gmail accounts with testing access"  and press the save button on the top.

Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've set a different value for serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending"); from IabHelper. Make sure you leave it with this value

Answer (score 0):

I had that same error and then noticed my phone was in Airplane Mode!  Once connectivity was restored, I was good to go.

Answer (score 0):

**IabHelper.java**

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
```

It is an error if it is not possible to specify correctly the action and packageName to `IInAppBillingService.aidl`.

Answer (score 0):

Have come up with the solution.

Try the below 3 steps:

1. Clear the cache of GooglePlay app and Google Play services app.
2. Remove IInAppBillingService.aidl file.
3. Copy the above file again from sdk folder and paste it to the aidl folder in my app.

This problem usually occurs when we copy the aidl file from one project to another project.

Answer (score 0):

I had a weird problem where billing worked on a real device but not on the emulator. Once I did a `Cold Boot`, the emulator's billing worked

[image]