# InAppBilling - getPurchases error : BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have an error in my application. In fact,ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE") return 3 ( BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE ). I don't understand why . Can you help me ? Thanks

```
Bundle ownedItems = null;
    try {
        ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, mContext.getPackageName(), "ITEM_TYPE_INAPP", null);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int response = ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
    Log.d("RESPONSE ", response+"");
    if (response == 0) {
        ArrayList<String> ownedSkus = 
      ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");
        return ownedSkus;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
```

EDIT : Solution which are proposed  in this topic don't solve my problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [IabResult: Billing service unavailable on device. (response: 3:Billing Unavailable)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889480/iabresult-billing-service-unavailable-on-device-response-3billing-unavailab)

Comment: Solution which are proposed  in this topic don't solve my problem

Comment: You have to create a signed release APK and test with that

Comment: I already test with a signed realease APK

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
Inapp skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3,getPackageName(), "Inapp", querySkus);
```

with

```
inapp skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3,getPackageName(), "inapp", querySkus);
```