# Inapp Billing unavailable in Some devices android (Not supported)

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have integrated inapp billing v3 in an android application. In newer devices which is working fine. But in some devices getting not supported error (BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE - 3 -1 Billing API version is not supported for the type requested). I need to support these devices also. How can it be possible ? can i integrate v2 api too for supporting these devices ?

Comment: this might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889480/iabresult-billing-service-unavailable-on-device-response-3billing-unavailab

Comment: try updating google play and google play services

Comment: Updated both but not working :(